# What is the method of returning the instance itself with the newly added configuration that allows chaining?

Tags: java, design, design-patterns, object-oriented-design

For example, with `Spark SQL`'s data [`DataFrameReader`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLContext.html), you can invoke something like `sqlContext.read().schema(customSchema).json(path)` where `schema` function returns `DataFrameReader` itself with the added configuration of `customSchema`. Similarly, Jackson's [`ObjectWriter`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html) has `with` function which returns `ObjectWriter` itself with some custom configuration passed through the `with` function.

First, I am curious if this way of configuring through chaining method has it's own name, so that I can research further

Second, would this kind of method fit for a data format converter class where HTML, JSON, and CSV will be converted to one another? What I am imagining is having a static `Converter` class that has `from` and `to` methods, where you specify the input and its dataformat type and the output and its dataformat type. So, it would look something like `Converter.from("inputPath", DataFormat.CSV).to("outputPath", DataFormat.JSON")` and the blackbox should handle the process. The main reason I wanted to try this out is that, right now I have a method for each conversion, such as `FromCSVToJSON`, but I didn't think it looks clean enough. Any alternative design suggestion for the Converter class is welcome.

Comment: Hm, `fluent interface` is the answer to the first question, but could I leave this question up for the second part of the question of whether this `fluent interface` suits for convert class?

Comment: This duplicate marker is wrong, it is a Fluent Interface not the builder pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "[Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)".  I personally like your fluent from() and to() methods - it's convenient and aesthetic.

Answer (score 0):

In Java it is known as a [Fluent Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).  It was popularised by Martin Fowler however the idea is actually much older.  It existed as [method cascading in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_cascading) and Smalltalk and is generally an inherent capability of functional languages.

A fluent interface would be useful for what you propose, but keep in mind it is a contract or interface not an implementation.  Use the interface segregation principle and delegate behaviour to maintain the single responsibility principle.